# Program exits after input before printing output

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I have written the following program, and it doesn't print properly. The console appears to simply close after I input the rate and hours.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double hours, rate, pay;
    // Get the number of hours worked.
    cout << "How many hours did you work? ";
    cin >> hours;
    // Get the hourly pay rate.
    cout << "How much do you get paid per hour? ";
    cin >> rate;
    // Calculate the pay.
    pay = hours * rate;
    // Display the pay.
    cout << "You have earned $" << pay << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'not debugging'?

Comment: This program runs, compiles and can be stepped into just fine.  I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: for me it just exits after u put in hours and time i dont understand i think its a configuration problem with visual studio?

Comment: @panzer67 -- *it just exits after u put in hours and time* -- What did you expect it to do?  Nothing in your program says "sit here and wait forever".

Comment: Hi @panzer67, I basically just [rewrote your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45910044/2) to be what I suspect you are trying to ask, as in its previous format it was very unclear. If this is not what you're trying to ask, you may roll the edit back and [edit] the question yourself to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The program prints the result and exits. That's normal behaviour. You can add `system("pause");` before the return statement to delay the closing of the console.